# Hide html till jQuery binding is done?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am wondering is it possible to detect when binding is done? For instance I have table that gets bound with the jquery datatables.net plugin that is in an ajax jquery ui tab.

So when the tab loads up the contents(the table). I have a jquery livequery waiting for the table to show up.

So when the table shows up it binds the datatables plugin to it. However I get a flicker of it switching over.

I am wondering is there away to hide elements till all binding is done?

Thanks

**Edit**

As some of have already pointed out that the datatables has some callbacks that may solve my problem. However this problem is not jsut limited to this plugin and could be limited to other plugins that maybe not have such callbacks or even built in events such as click,submit or whatever.

Granted some of them like click probably are not as notice as a plugin rendering as by the time the user gets to click that element the binding is probably done.

I guess I am trying to see if it is possible to delay a elements from being rendered till everything that is done to them is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataTables plugin has hooks for [many callback functions](http://www.datatables.net/usage/callbacks), you may have success with hiding the table initially and showing it using **fnInitComplete**.

Comment: That seems to work for this plugin not sure about other plugins though that don't have these callbacks. I can't give you examples of them yet as I have not implemented all of them and have not checked if they have callbacks are not.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use the [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event.

> The load event is sent to an element
>   when it and all sub-elements have been
>   completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the window object.

```
$('#whatever').load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});
```

In your case you hide your elements by default, then show it again inside the load function after your binding has loaded.

Comment: I don't think this is quite what he wants is it? He wants to know when the datatables plugin specifically is done loading data.

Comment: I don't know what the database plugin is or how it works. The answer based on what i understood from his question. The plugin should have sometype of a callback function.

Comment: I can see that you don't know this. I'm currently perusing the API and not seeing anything for that.

Comment: I should also mention that my problem is not specific to just the datatables plugin. This could be built in events(such as click or whatever they are just not as noticeable). would be nice to pick and choose elements that need to be fully bound before shown to the user.

Comment: The question is vague, you will not get a definite answer unless you provide some specific code to look at. It's hard to guess.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the problem is similar to FOUC, so your answer might be similar to solutions for that, i.e. hide everything, then have jQ add or remove a class after all the other jQ has run.

Comment: It is similar and that's what I thought of doing hiding everything and then showing everything. The question though is when do you show everything? I don't know how long everything takes to bind and I am sure the time varies. That's why I am trying to figure out if there is some way of checking when everything is bound.

Comment: I don't know how long binding takes, either, or whether it is asynchronous or not.  You might just try experimenting with it.